# Ember.js - Clicking on one button to trigger click event on another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ember.js

I want to click on button 2 to trigger a click event on button 1.  I can accomplish this tasks using JQuery.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<input id="upload_input" type="file" name="files[]" style="display:none" />
<button id="button-2">Upload File</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#upload_input').trigger('click');
```

I'm new to Ember.js and I would like to accomplish the same functionality within the Ember.View context.  Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What does button 1 or 2 actually do?  Are they calling an action on a controller?

Comment: Hi Kingpin2k, I updated the sample to reflect the use case I want to use with Ember.js.  I'm new to ember.js so I am having a hard time to get this scenario working.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey Kingpin2k,  I love to hear your thoughts and/or a sample you can help put together for me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the change event on the input.  You can then post the form, or use ajax to post back asynchronously.  Here's a simple example:

### View

```
App.UploadButtonView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'input',
  attributeBindings: ['type'],
  type: 'file',

  change: function(e){
    var self = this;
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.$().get(0).files[0]);
    $.ajax({
      url: '/file_upload/', 
      type: 'POST',
      //Ajax events
      success: function(data){ },
      error: function(){ },
      // Form data
      data: formData,
      //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false
    });
  }
});
```

### Template

```
{{view 'uploadButton'}}
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jameg/1/edit

Comment: Hi Kingpin2k,  thank you for the great sample.  I would love to have a sample where the upload button with the id=button-2 click event to trigger the App.UploadButtonView change handle.  The reason I want this feature is because I want to style my own button because the input type=file button is rather ugly.  is this possible?  Let me know.  Talk to you soon.

Comment: Just wrap the button in a div and style it, http://geniuscarrier.com/how-to-style-a-html-file-upload-button-in-pure-css/

Comment: Kingpin2, Thank you for the great resources.  It definitely helped my out.  Best Regards.  I would give you a thumbs up for your response today but i do not have enought reputation points. Once I get the points, I will give you the points.